# Filter data using mongoose populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relationship

I have two data structures "database" and "components"

```
const DatabaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    components: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Components', required: false }],
});
```

```
const ComponentsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    updatedAt: Date,
});
```

I want to filter all items in the database by component names

search rule I'm using

```
Database.find({
    components: { $elemMatch:  { name: /antr/i } }
}).populate({
    path: 'components',
    select: 'name -_id'
}).select(['descript','components']).exec( (err,data) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.json(data);
});
```

however always return an empty element

Comment: Can you please provide a sample document of each collection. Is you components field in database collection related to name field in components collection? or to _id ?

Comment: **SchemaDatabase**
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4979d52a17d10a6c8de81b"),
    "components" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857951f")
    ]
}

**SchemaComponents**
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857951f"),
    "name" : "antracito",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-05T12:10:56.777Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

I basically want to filter all schemaDatabase records that have a particular component by name

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you try this ::::::>>> Database.find({}).populate({
    path: 'components',
    match : {name: /antr/i},
    select: 'name -_id'
}).exec( (err,data) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.json(data);
});

Comment: using math he returned me: [{"components":[{"name":"antracito"}],"_id":"5d4979d52a17d10a6c8de81b"},{"components":[{"name":"antracito"}],"_id":"5d497cf52a17d10a6c8de81c"},{"components":**[]**,"_id":"5d4dce1bdb000e29ac4e5734"},{"components":**[]**,"_id":"5d4dd45bdb000e29ac4e5735"}]...

How do I remove empty components? (without using callback)

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: This is because of match, which means match doesn't find appropriate results for all records in Components collection for elements in components array of database collection, You can also implement $lookup which is similar to populate - that way it would be easy !!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

As I've already suggested you can use this :

```
Database.find({})
    .populate({ path: 'components', match: { name: /antr/i }, select: 'name -_id' })
    .exec((err, data) => { console.log(err); res.json(data); });
```

Since you're seeing empty array's is because of the filter query in `match` which doesn't find appropriate documents in components collection w.r.t. ObjectIds in components array of database document, this is normal. May be you can filter those out in code, as you aren't looking in that way, You can use mongoDB's `$lookup` from aggregation framework which is equivalent to `.populate()` from mongoose.

```
Database.aggregate(
    [{
        $lookup: {
            from: "components",
            "let": { "ids": "$components" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$ids'] } } }],
            as: "dbComponentsArray"
        }
    }, { $unwind: '$dbComponentsArray' }, { $match: { 'dbComponentsArray.name': /antr/i } },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id', dbComponentsArray: { $push: '$dbComponentsArray' }, data: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }, { $addFields: { 'data.dbComponentsArray': '$dbComponentsArray' } },
    { $replaceRoot: { 'newRoot': '$data' } }])
```

**Sample Data in collections :**

**components :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857959f"),
    "name" : "antracito",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-05T12:10:56.777Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857958f"),
    "name" : "anacito",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-05T12:10:56.777Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857951f"),
    "name" : "antracito",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-05T12:10:56.777Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857952f"),
    "name" : "anacito",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-05T12:10:56.777Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**database :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4979d52a17d10a6c8de81b"),
    "components" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857951f"), 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857952f"), 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857953f"), 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857959f")
    ]
}
```

**Output :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4979d52a17d10a6c8de81b"),
    "components" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857951f"), 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857952f"), 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857953f"), 
        ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857959f")
    ],
    "dbComponentsArray" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857959f"),
            "name" : "antracito",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-05T12:10:56.777Z"),
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d481cd098ba991c0857951f"),
            "name" : "antracito",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-05T12:10:56.777Z"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```