# Combining Mongo Schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB Schema to let users create an account using passport.js. It looks like this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: String,
    password: String
});
```

I also have a JobsSchema that looks like this:

```
var JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobname: String,
    score: Number,
});
```

**Question**: Is it possible to somehow add the "Jobs" Data to the User? I'd like to be able to access the jobs data by user... So for example I want to be able to show job data associated with a user like...

```
<%= user.jobName %>
```

Comment: Not pin pointed to the problem but this might be of help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57834117/6082280). Does job to user has 1 to 1 relation?

Comment: Interesting thanks! Yes the job data will belong to each user specifically

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi : When it comes to mongoDB data is denormalized, How many fields do you've in JobSchema ? There can be certain ways to do this, especially if jobSchema has low no.of fields & doesn't need much maintenance, needs to be accessed every time you access user) - Have it as sub-document in user document itself !! Let's say you need to access it seperately more often/job document size is large enough & needs constant updates &need not to be accessed every time w.r.t. user then pls check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497393/filter-data-using-mongoose-populate/57617145#57617145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the job id in the user schema and use a [populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method to get the details of the job in the user object.

User:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: String,
    password: String,
    job: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job'}
});
```

when you make a query, you should use populate() like:

```
db.users.find({}).populate('job');
```

So the response will be like:

```
response = {
  user: 'Sam',
  password: 123,
  job: {
    jobName: 'Manager',
    score: 5
  }
}
```

Now, you can access like : `response.job.jobName`

If you need the object path as user.jobname, then you could normalize the response manually by constructing a new object